# WPF BInding selected Item Property of list box

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following scenario
I have list of computers
List computers;

and computer have the following properties

```
Computer{
  User current-user;
  String name;

}

User{
   Date-time Start Time;
   Date Time Elapsed;
  ....}
```

I want to have the following view

**List of Computer Names in list view**

and **when selected details of current User** In that computer ![enter image description here][1]

I need some hint how do i do this on **XAML**  c**omputer and user objects implement Inotifypropertychanged**  interface and my collection is **Observable collection**

This is a client server application so i am assuming with the above conditions the UI will update with the current user information from client computers. THANK YOU!

Comment: Please fix your question so we can try to answer it... :)

Comment: It would be much easy to understand if i provided picture but ,i have no enough reputations to upload picture

Comment: @እከሌ put a link to it ...i will edit

Comment: @ Joseph   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B046b0DMfDUKT2ZNdGtYYU94Mmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't upload images from locations that need passwords to access them like yours does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

1- Bind you computers list to a listbox

```
<ListBox Name="ComputersListbox" ItemsSource={Binding YourPropertyListHere}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text={Binding name}>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Bind the selected item of the listbox to the datacontext of the grid layout:

```
<Grid Name="UserDetailGrid" DataContext={Binding SelectedItem.current-user,ElementName=ComputersListbox}><!--All the controls in the grid will consider their datasource is the SelectedItem.current-user in the listbox which is a computer-->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Elapsed} />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text={Binding StartTime} />
</Grid>
```

When ever you change the selected item, the data in the grid will be modified. Since you implement INotifyPropertyChanged, the view will be updated when you change the properties in the viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you so much !! if u can agian help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161440/wpf-dispatcher-timer-tick-event-not-firering